# Wordpress table doesn't look correctly using text and input boxes

Tags: html, css, input, html-table

How can I add text and an input textbox in the same line?

I'm using Wordpress, and I am adding that kind of things to a page, but the format seems to be different and the elements appears in different lines.

I'm using regular code like this:

```
<form width="300px">
<a>First name:</a> <input type="text" name="firstname" /><BR />
<a>Last name:</a> <input type="text" name="lastname" />
</form> 

<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>row 1, <input type="text" name="firstname" /></td>
<td>row 1, <input type="text" name="firstname" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2, <input type="text" name="firstname" /></td>
<td>row 2, <input type="text" name="firstname" /></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to span your td across both columns

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"> row 1, <input type="text" name="firstname" /></td>
</tr>
```

or, you're table is too narrow, here is how to set your table to 500 pixels wide.

```
<table width="500px">
```

you can then change the widths of your table rows if you are having an issue with a column being too narrow.

```
<td width="80%"> </td>
```

Comment: hmm,  for some reason it it not working, I'm still getting the same result =(

@dylan-hayes

Comment: do you have a css file being refereneced that is adding styles to your <table> <td> <tr> tags?

Comment: This is what it does have for table objects.


table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
 background: transparent;
 border: 0;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}

table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

#content table {
 /*border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;*/
 margin: 0;
 text-align: left;
 /*width: 100%;*/
}
#content tr th,
#content thead th {
 color: #888;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: 400;
 line-height: 18px;
 padding: 9px 24px;
}
#content tr td {
 /*border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7;*/
 padding: 6px 24px;
}

Comment: looks like all that would apply to your table is

tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td { background: transparent; border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; vertical-align: baseline; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }

you could add a css class of your own <table class="mytable"> and <td class="mycolumn" then define it in css as .mytable {} and .mycolumn {} and add your own styles to set widths and margins to whatever you like.

Comment: In a blank file it works, but in my wp template for some reason it is not working.

Looking at the source code when the page is displayed, it is a little different. look the line break that actually I didn't put in the code.

<td id="mycol" colspan="2" width="50%"style="padding=0;marging:0px;display:block;position:relative;" >row 1<br />
<input id="myin" type="text" name="firstname" style="color:#000" /></td>

Comment: you should be able to just removed those <br /> tags then correct? Or are they being inserted somehow? It is possible this is happening through a javascript/jquery script of some sort.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5205/discussion-between-marco-and-dylan-hayes)

Answer (score 0):

I've added your code to a blank html file and this is my output. This is what you're looking for correct?
You're markup is fine if this is what you're trying to achieve.

[image]

This is from the following code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form width="300px">
    <a>First name:</a> <input type="text" name="firstname" /><BR />
    <a>Last name:</a> <input type="text" name="lastname" />
</form> 

<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>row 1, <input type="text" name="firstname" /></td>
    <td>row 1, <input type="text" name="firstname" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>row 2, <input type="text" name="firstname" /></td>
    <td>row 2, <input type="text" name="firstname" /></td>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Resolution:** After trying my previous answers marco was still getting multiple rows for his controls. Marco examined his markup and found extra `<br>` tags being added. I suggested this must be coming from script somewhere in the theme itself. We tracked down his theme's script folder and Marco was able to pinpoint the line of code that was adding the `<br>` tags.

**From Marco:** "Dylan, the function `wpautop($pee, $br = 0)` did the trick, if it is set to `1` it will insert auto breaks for averything !!!, in `0` it will not work like that and your code will look like what you are expecting!"

You can follow our chat:
[Here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5205/discussion-between-marco-and-dylan-hayes)